# travis ci do nothing

Tags: docker, yaml, travis-ci

I am new on Travis CI and I am trying to deploy my hobby project to AWS by Travis but in my first commit nothing happened here is my .travis.yml:

```
sudo: required
language: generic

services:
  - docker

before_install:
  - docker build -t aaa/fakewebappapi -f ./api/Dockerfile.dev ./api

script:
  - docker run -e CI=true aaa/fakewebappapi npm run test

after_success:
  - docker build -t aaa/fakewebappclient -f ./client/Dockerfile.dev ./client
  - docker build -t aaa/fakewebappapi -f ./api/Dockerfile.dev ./api
  - docker build -t aaa/fakewebappnginx -f ./nginx/Dockerfile.dev ./nginx
  - echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_ID" --password-stdin
  - docker push aaa/fakewebappclient
  - docker push aaa/fakewebappapi
  - docker push aaa/fakewebappnginx
```

Each docker work correctly but when I push the repository to my GitHub nothing changed. Also I checked my GitHub profile and travis connected it succesfully.

Also there is no log in travis-ci.com when I see other travis project on YouTube everyone has log screen in built screen.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using tabs instead of spaces.